# Why "bootstrap" key in @NgModule is not working when you build the same structure than App.module.ts?

Tags: angular

I need to create a admin module in my project and I intend use a layout to all my admin. So I think use NgModule Bootstrap is the best option in Angular.

```
// ./admin.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    //...
    RouterModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AdminComponent],
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

```
// ./admin.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```
// admin.component.html

<app-admin-layout> <!-- Layout Component -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-admin-layout>
```

```
// .admin-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

However, Bootstrap doesn't work. The page only show HomeModules page without bootstrap component.

How can I solve it?

Comment: could you re-create this on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lvcwcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hierarchy of routing module and layout component was wrong. Also you need to care full about router-outlet/router-outlet usage. Here is a [official guide for you](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Here is a running [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjzyau?file=src/app/admin/admin-routing.module.ts)